Expo: run "npx expo run:ios" shows "Cause: No podspec found for `@vimeiro-co` in `../node_modules/@vimeiro-co/react-native-render-html`"
when I run npx expo run:ios, the message shows
"Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: No podspec found for `@vimeiro-co` in `../node_modules/@vimeiro-co/react-native-render-html`"

but I can see the podspec file at: node_modules/@vimeiro-co/react-native-render-htmlreact-native-render-html.podspec, how can I fix it? thanks.
I saw the command npx expo run:ios on expo documentation and knew it will create an ios/ directory that include files about iOS app.
Before I ran the command above, I ran npx expo-doctor to check the project, and the result is good. So I ran npx expo run:ios and later it shows
"Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: No podspec found for `@vimeiro-co` in `../node_modules/@vimeiro-co/react-native-render-html`"


I think maybe I found the answer. The orginal podspec file is like:
``

I think maybe I found the answer. The orginal podspec file is like:
require 'json'

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'package.json')))

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = package['name']
  s.version      = package['version']
  s.summary      = package['description']
  s.license      = package['license']

  s.authors      = package['author']
  s.homepage     = package['homepage']
  s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"

  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-render-html.git", :tag => "v#{s.version}" }
  s.source_files  = "ios/**/*.{h,m}"

  s.dependency 'React-Core'
end

Then I try to fill package information with:
require 'json'

package = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(__dir__, 'package.json')))

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = 'react-native-render-html'
  s.version      = '6.3.5'
  s.summary      = 'A library to render HTML in React Native.'
  s.license      = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }

  s.authors      = { 'Vimeiro' => 'support@vimeiro.co' }
  s.homepage     = 'https://github.com/vimeiro-co/react-native-render-html'
  s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"

  s.source       = { :git => 'https://github.com/vimeiro-co/react-native-render-html.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.source_files  = 'ios/**/*.{h,m,swift}'

  s.dependency 'React'
end

and pass the building.
